# JSON.parse - How to sort data

Tags: java, json

I have data in this form

```
var line            = new Vector();  
var dataJsonParse   = JSON.parse(jsonString); 
var row;
for (var rowK in  dataJsonParse) {
    row = dataJsonParse[rowK];
    for (var fKey in row )  {                
        line.add( row[fKey] );  
    }  
}
```

returns:

1,2,3,4,5,6,z,z,z,z,z,z,l,l,l,l,l,l,9,9,9,9,9,9

I would like in this form:

1,z,l,9,2,z,l,9,3,z,l,9,4,z,l,9,5,z,l,9,6,z,l,9

Comment: Can you post the example data you're parsing?

Comment: Hum the posted code is a mix between javascript and java, you need to choose!

Comment: You might also want to explain a little bit more your "sorting"